# How to know if a scanner has done scanning barcode in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I want to perform some actions when my app scans a barcode. For that i need to know whenever my device scanner scans a barcode. Barcode contains a string which i want to use in my app. I searched a lot and tried to solve the problem using following code but i am not sure if i am on the right track because its not working:

In my onCreate method i am registering a broadcast receiver:

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
 filter.addDataScheme("file");

 receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      System.out.println("intent action:"+action);
      System.out.println("intent recieved");
     }
 };

 getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But i never receive anything. Any idea why or any other solution to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

`Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED`

> Broadcast Action: The media scanner has finished scanning a directory. The path to the scanned directory is contained in the Intent.mData field.

that have nothing to do with barcode scanning. You have to see which library/method you're using to scan a barcode.

If you're using the XIng library I'm sure you have to call an activityForResult and then you just catch `onActivityResult`

Comment: I am using that when i am scanning using camera. Right now i am using Motorola ET1 which has a scanner. If an EditText is focused and i press scan button, i get information in that EditText. I want my app to know when scanner is done with scanning so i can perform some action on the information i get from barcode without pressing any button. Is there any way to tell app that scanning is done so i can perform action without pressing a buttonö

Comment: I understood what you're doing, but my answer was pointing it out that you did not understood what that Intent does. It have nothing to do with the barcode scanner. It's about the media gallery file scanner. You probably can do what u want by adding a TextChangeListener or EditorActionListener on your EditText